# UseKestrel with listen options

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server

I have a problem adding the listen options for my ASP.NET Core solution. I have tried a brand new solution, appending the program.cs to:

```
      .UseKestrel(options =>
      {
          options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
          options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
          {
              listenOptions.UseHttps("/HTTPS_cert/https.pfx", "****");
          });
      })
```

The error I get is: "The name 'IPAddress' does not exist in the current context.

If I e.g. try with:

```
options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
```

The server starts just fine. What am I missing?

I am using VS for Mac.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just missing an import for `System.Net` as that is where the [`IPAddress.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any?view=netcore-2.0) static field is. Just add this to your file:

```
using System.Net;
```